# 2 in a row game in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c#-express-2010

[image: the board]

above is the image of the board

i am finding it hard to work out how to detect 2 color in a row to determine winner
with out using brute-force enumeration..

i have an algorithm and i have been trying to implement it but i cant seem to get it working
would anyone know how to do this.. would be great help thanks..

i want to detect winner diagonal vertical and horizontal..

p.s i don't normally ask for solutions but this time i really need some help. many thanks

here is the code that i have for the program that allows u to put the peaces

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private Button[] btns;
        private Button[] btns2;
        private Button[] btns3;
        public Color[] col;
      //  public var x;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            btns = new Button[2] { button2, button3 };
            btns2 = new Button[2] { button4, button5 };
            btns3 = new Button[2] { button9, button8 };
            col = new Color[2] { Color.Red, Color.Yellow };
           Color x = col[0];
            Color y = col[1];


        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (var btn in btns)
            {
                btn.Enabled = false;
                btn.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
            }

            foreach (var btn in btns2)
            {
                btn.Enabled = false;
                btn.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
            }
            foreach (var btn in btns3)
            {
                btn.Enabled = false;
                btn.BackColor = Color.LightCyan;
            }
        }




        public int state;
        int cc = 0;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var btn in btns)
            {
                  {
                    if (!btn.Enabled)
                    {
                        btn.Enabled = true;

                        if (cc == 0)
                        {
                            cc = 1;
                            btn.BackColor = col[0];

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cc = 0;
                            btn.BackColor = col[1];
                        }



                        return;
                    }

                }
            }       
        }


        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var btn in btns2)
            {
                if (!btn.Enabled)
                {
                    btn.Enabled = true;

                    if (cc == 0)
                    {
                        cc = 1;
                        btn.BackColor = col[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cc = 0;
                        btn.BackColor = col[1];

                    }



                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            foreach (var btn in btns3)
            {
                if (!btn.Enabled)
                {
                    btn.Enabled = true;

                    if (cc == 0)
                    {
                        cc = 1;
                        btn.BackColor = col[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cc = 0;
                        btn.BackColor = col[1];

                    }



                    return;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen your question several times before here. Are you actually only looking for matches of 2? I recall you saying that this is eventually going to be a type of connect 4 or 5 game?

Comment: yep it will be connect 4 but i was thinking if i learn how to do connect 2 i can move on by extending it

Comment: I don't think thats a good way of approaching it. How big is the entire grid for the game going to be?

Comment: I think it's a reasonable approach, provided that you're specifically looking out for the things which are feasible in the smaller set that aren't in the larger one.  Such as brute-force checking.

Comment: @Tacit can we get some feedback regarding the multiple answers that have been provided? Do any of these make sense to you? Do you think you know enough to implement any of these solutions? Do you need more clarification? etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be doing this logic with buttons. Create a game class that implements the logic and that you can control by function calls containing X and Y parameters.

Then in each button click, you call the game logic like `game.MakeMove(0, 0);` if the button in the top left is clicked.

Profit of this: it is testable and the user interface can easily be changed.

Comment: This is definitely the best way to go about solving the problem. However I feel that the original poster is probably new to programming/possibly working on a homework assignment so it might be a little outside the scope of what can be accomplished for this project.

Comment: yep ur right @jesse i really need some help on this part.. would u be willing to comunicate by email maybe i can send u my work pls

Comment: @jesse no its not im just looking to enhance my skills im trying to learn how to deal with arrays and 2d arrays i have now changed my code and it works using a 2d array but im still struggling to do the winning detection i love programming so im trying to set myself mini projects to learn it properly

Comment: If you've got things working using a 2D array consider trying to implement the logic that I gave you in my original answer. If you get something at least started using that then I will consider taking a look and giving you some pointers in the right direction but gotta see some effort first ;)

Comment: Also, considering picking one of the answers here and marking this question solved as you know what you need to do to solve this. You just need to work on implementation now. Stack Overflow isn't going to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1):

Two options.  The simpler one is to create a `Button[][]` array, and populate it so that it matches the actual locations of the buttons.  Then you can check other buttons by index.

The more complicated one is to create a subclass of `Button` which knows it's own position in the grid (`X` and `Y` properties) and knows how to find an adjoining button.  Then you can get a list of all adjoining buttons of the same color, and build up a chain that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think the logical approach would be without any code cause I'm at work at the moment and can't test anything out. You need to arrange your buttons or pieces or whatever your game will ultimately be in some kind of 2 dimensional array/collection with corresponding values for the X and Y axis.

When a button is clicked, you only need to check the relevant touching buttons to check for a potential match. For example. Lets imagine that the bottom left button is at position 0,0. If it is clicked you simply need to check the buttons at 1,0 and 0,1 to see if they are the same color to know a match has been made.

This can be easily extended for however many matches you need for a valid set. It also allows you to avoid the "brute force" approach. In the exact same scenario as before if you are looking for 4 in a row and 0,1 isn't the same color you don't need to check 0,2 or 0,3 or anything else along that axis because we already know there is no match there.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a multidimensional array to represent your data - buttons. In other words, a matrix.

Basically, you could declare your buttons like this:

```
private Button[,] buttons = new Button[2, 3];
```

An MSDN page explains [how multidimensional arrays work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Then, you could iterate on the array to detect any logic - horizontal, vertical, diagonal matching, etc. You could write something like this:

```
bool hasAWinner = false;
// for each line
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    Dictionary<Color, int> numberOfbuttonsWithColor = new Dictionary<Color, int>();
    numberOfbuttonsWithColor[Color.Red] = 0;
    numberOfbuttonsWithColor[Color.Yellow] = 0;

    // detect if there is at least two buttons of the same color
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        Color currentButtonColor = buttons[i,j].BackColor;
        numberOfbuttonsWithColor[currentButtonColor]++;
        if (numberOfbuttonsWithColor[currentButtonColor] == 2) {
            hasAWinner = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (hasAWinner) break;
}


// execute victory actions
if (hasAWinner) {
    Console.writeline(String.format("Color {0} wins!", currentButtonColor);
}
```

Comment: why u have the value 0 for bot red and yellow

Comment: that's for counting the number of buttons with that color, in that row. Then, when we start counting each row, we need to reset that value to 0

Comment: would u be willing to communicate by email to help me do this cos im finding it hard to make it work maybe i can send u my work

Comment: sorry, i'm not that available

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

Name each button after its column and row. i.e. btn00 (top left), btnNN (bottom right, with N being the amount of rows and columns, assuming a square), etc.

On each event handler, save the name of the clicked button, and its color.
Then itereate over each color's collection of clicked button and compare indexes.
If you find two button names that match the following criteria, it's two in a row:

```
if ((Math.Abs(index0ButtonA - index0ButtonB) == 1 && index1ButtonA == index1ButtonB) || ( Math.Abs(index1ButtonA - index1ButtonB) == 1 && index0ButtonA == index0ButtonB)
{
     twoInARow = true;
}
```

Comment: This might work though I don't favour the idea of using the button names as a means of identifying their location. This is not good coding practice.

Comment: You could also store the column/row in the Tag, maybe that could be a good way (though not sure if the Tag is available in WinForms, that is WPF).